# insertAfter() slow or not working at all with resize()-event

Tags: jquery

When I resize my browser, everything in my function works except the insertafter() and appendto(), they work if i resize the window very slowly, (sometimes!), but I need it to work as soon as it hits the resize mark. What can I do about this?

I have the following code:

```
    responsiveMenu: function () {
        if ((window).matchMedia("(min-width: 767.98px)").matches) {
            $("#headerSearch").insertAfter(".search-field--webb");
            $(".list-item").removeClass("without-before-element").addClass("d-flex");
            $("a.d-block").removeClass("p-2");
        }else {
            $("#headerSearch").appendTo(".search-field--mobile");
            $(".hamburgermenu-button").addClass("collapsed");
            $('.extended-navigation').removeClass('show');
            $(".list-item").addClass("without-before-element").removeClass("d-flex");
            $("a.d-block").not('.watchlist-mobile').addClass("p-2");
        }
    }
```

And I run it with this code:

```
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            if((window).matchMedia("(min-width: 766.98px)").matches){
                Blabla.responsiveMenu();
            };
        });
```

But as I said, everything in my responsiveMenu function works immediately except the insertAfter() and appendTo(), unless sometimes when I resize very slowly. Is there another way to make this switch of DOM-elements at a certain width? It's one element that I move from one place to another depending on how big the screen is.

Comment: can you check your inspector and see if your element gets moved more than once while you resize the window?

Comment: Well, it gets moved over and over again but to the place it's supposed to be. So over 767.98px it get moved to search-field--webb over and over, and under to search-field--mobile over and over. Which is fine really, as long as the element is where it's supposed to be. This is if i go really slow though.

Comment: I think you should check if element has already moved before actually invoking insertBefore or appendTo